# Assign a calculated value using user defined function

Tags: excel, vba, reference, cell

This version is cleaner and easier to read. The conditions are evaluated top-down, so once a condition is met, the subsequent conditions won't be checked.

```
Function GRADE(ByVal cellref As Range) As String
    Dim cr As Integer
    cr = CInt(cellref.Value)
    
    If cr >= 95 Then
        GRADE = "A++"
    ElseIf cr >= 90 Then
        GRADE = "A+"
    ElseIf cr >= 85 Then
        GRADE = "A"
    ElseIf cr >= 80 Then
        GRADE = "B++"
    ElseIf cr >= 75 Then
        GRADE = "B+"
    ElseIf cr >= 70 Then
        GRADE = "B"
    ElseIf cr >= 60 Then
        GRADE = "C"
    ElseIf cr >= 50 Then
        GRADE = "D"
    ElseIf cr >= 40 Then
        GRADE = "E"
    Else
```

Comment: First, the type should be Strng in `Function GRADE(ByVal cellref As Range) As String`. Second, replace `ActiveCell.Value2 = CDbl(gd)` with `GRADE = gd`. Last, I don't know why you try to convert string to double `CDbl(gd)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Excel formulas provide an option without needing **macros enabled**. Nested `IF` statements are understandable but require multiple levels. `LOOKUP` is a more concise approach.

For example, the formula (in cell B2) converts a score to a grade:

> =LOOKUP(A2,{0,40,50,60,70,75,80,85,90,95},{"U","E","D","C","B","B+","B++","A","A+","A++"})

An alternative is placing the score and grade ranges on the sheet, then naming them `_Score` and `_Grade`. The formula simplifies to:

> =LOOKUP(A2,_Score,_Grade)

Leveraging LOOKUP and defined names keeps the formula tidy.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### A Grading UDF

[image]

- I would suggest getting rid of the rounding and reducing the numbers by `0.5`, the latter, if you really think that's what you need.

```vb
Function GRADE(ByVal cell As Range) As String
     
    ' Ensure single cell.
    If cell.Cells.CountLarge > 1 Then Exit Function ' result is ""
     
    Dim CellValue As Variant: CellValue = cell.Value
     
    Dim gd As String
     
    If VarType(CellValue) = vbDouble Then ' is a number
        CellValue = Application.Round(CellValue, 0) ' sure about rounding?
        Select Case CellValue
            Case Is >= 95: gd = "A++"
            Case Is >= 90: gd = "A+"
            Case Is >= 85: gd = "A"
            Case Is >= 80: gd = "B++"
            Case Is >= 75: gd = "B+"
            Case Is >= 70: gd = "B"
            Case Is >= 60: gd = "C"
            Case Is >= 50: gd = "D"
            Case Is >= 40: gd = "E"
            Case Else: gd = "U" ' <40
        End Select
    Else ' is not a number
        gd = "" ' or "U" or "NA" or...
    End If
    
    GRADE = gd

End Function
```

**A VBA Rounding Reminder**

```
Sub RoundTest()
    Debug.Print CLng(1.5), Round(1.5), Application.Round(1.5, 0)
    Debug.Print CLng(2.5), Round(2.5), Application.Round(2.5, 0)
End Sub
```

**Result**

```
 2             2             2 
 2             2             3
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you provided seems to be a VBA function intended to grade a student based on their score. However, there are a few issues with the function:

1. The function is supposed to return an `Integer`, but you're trying to assign a `String` value (`gd`) to it.
2. The function is attempting to assign a value to `ActiveCell`. This is not a good practice for a function. Functions should return values, not modify cells directly.
3. The line `ActiveCell.Value2 = CDbl(gd)` will throw an error because you're trying to convert a string (`gd`) to a double.

Here's a corrected version of the function:

```vb
Function GRADE(ByVal cellref As Range) As String
    Dim cr As Integer
    cr = CInt(cellref.Value)
    
    If (cr >= 95) Then
        GRADE = "A++"
    ElseIf ((cr >= 90) And (cr <= 94)) Then
        GRADE = "A+"
    ElseIf ((cr >= 85) And (cr <= 89)) Then
        GRADE = "A"
    ElseIf ((cr >= 80) And (cr <= 84)) Then
        GRADE = "B++"
    ElseIf ((cr >= 75) And (cr <= 79)) Then
        GRADE = "B+"
    ElseIf ((cr >= 70) And (cr <= 74)) Then
        GRADE = "B"
    ElseIf ((cr >= 60) And (cr <= 69)) Then
        GRADE = "C"
    ElseIf ((cr >= 50) And (cr <= 59)) Then
        GRADE = "D"
    ElseIf ((cr >= 40) And (cr <= 49)) Then
        GRADE = "E"
    Else
        GRADE = "U"
    End If
End Function
```

With this corrected function, you can use it in Excel like this: `=GRADE(A1)` where `A1` contains the score. The function will return the grade as a string.

Comment: In addition,  all the `And (cr <= ...)` clauses are unnecessary and can be deleted.  And all the brackets in the `If/ElseIf` clauses are unnecessary and can be deleted